# How can we future-proof against iOS 6's upcoming UDID/UUID removal if we're using PhoneGap?

Tags: iphone, cordova, uuid

We're currently using PhoneGap for our mobile applications, and I know they have device.udid (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_device_device.md.html#device.uuid) to get unique identifiers. What's the best way to future-proof so that our current applications will work when iOS 6 comes out? Should we start using some of the other solutions out there (MAC address, etc.) to ensure future-compatibility?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check out the documentation for `CFUUIDCreate`

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFUUIDRef/Reference/reference.html

I use the method below to create a UUID and save it to the user preferences the first time the app is started:

```
- (NSString *)getUUID
{
    NSString *UUID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"uniqueID"];
    if (!UUID)
    {
        CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
        CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
        CFRelease(theUUID);
        UUID = [(__bridge NSString*)string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-"withString:@""];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:UUID forKey:@"uniqueID"];
    }
    return UUID;
}
```

Comment: Perfect!.  I'd add [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; after you save the uniqueID to the user defaults. Also, syncing the UniqueID using iCloud seems like a good idea in some cases as it identifies one particular user no matter how many devices he/she has.

Comment: This approach has the disadvantage that the UUID can be copied from device to device by copying the defaults file. So one cannot use it to make for example InAppPurchases non transferable to another device without restoring the purchases through the app store.

Comment: @cat you could store this in a non backed up location or in the keychain and avoid the backup problem?

Comment: iOS6 provides good replacement for UUID: [UIDevice identifierForVendor] The advantage is that it does not need to be stored. However "Bill the Lizard" deleted the answer here, but probably you can find the doc yourself.

Answer (score 6):

I've been using this GitHub project that essentially takes the MAC address of the device and hashes it with the bundle ID:

[gekitz / UIDevice-with-UniqueIdentifier-for-iOS-5](https://github.com/gekitz/UIDevice-with-UniqueIdentifier-for-iOS-5)

Comment: I love this method, but has any app been rejected because of the use of MAC address to generate a device-unique identifiable code?  Seems like it'd bring the same issues to Apple as UUID does.

Comment: @Ben YMMV, but I have not had a problem in the App Store with this approach.  From a privacy perspective, using the MAC address is worse because the UDID changes when it is setup as a new device.  Not so with MAC address.  But such is life when you take away an API and don't replace it with something suitable: people will find ways to accomplish the same result.

Comment: In the commit message there is a lengthy discussion that this library has a huge privacy leak. Anyone looking to replace the device specific UUID should consider not using this library, or risk their users privacy.