# PhoneGap 1.0 app Submit to AppStore fails

Tags: ios, cordova, app-store, appstore-approval, udid

We have an old app created with PhoneGap version 1.0. There is *absolutely no chance* to migrate to latest PhoneGap/Cordova because of *huge changes* in both iOS/JS code required.

An attempt to upload an app compiled with iOS SDK 6.1 failed with message: "Apps are not permitted to access the UDID and must not use the uniqueIdentifier method of UIDevice. Please update your apps and servers to associate users with the Vendor or Advertising identifiers introduced in iOS 6.".

PhoneGap 1.0 sources are not available in public, it's distributed as compiled framework.

Does anyone have an idea how to workaround this issue?

Comment: PhoneGap has always been open source, even before Nitobi's acquisition by Adobe.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Any idea I can get sources? Goooogled a lot without success. Thanks.

Comment: Hmmmm... now *that's* a fine question. Pre-1.0 source is at https://github.com/sintaxi/phonegap/tree/master/iphone. However, I am not seeing the source distributions on GitHub again until after the creation of Apache Cordova.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Thank you. Will try use sources/recompile without using UDID calls.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the old apache-incubator versions of Cordova that were on Github have been removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Crazy, but WORKING solution** (hack)

Well, once PhoneGap 1.0 is provided as compiled lib, we can try to change the compiled binary itself.

The reason of Apple reject are calls to [UIDevice uniqueIdentifier] method deprecated in iOS 6. If your app (JS code) does not use UDID provided by PhoneGap (actually, have no idea is there a way to get it), it's safe (!? see NOTE bellow) to change the call of *uniqueIdentifier* to any other method returning NSString of UIDevice class.

I've used +(NSString *)systemVersion - getter of systemVersion property.

**So, get any HEX editor and open file: /users/Shared/PhoneGap/Frameworks/PhoneGap.framework/PhoneGap
replace *uniqueIdentifier* with *systemVersion\0\0\0***.

\0 - are zero code bytes, needed to align the length of new name which is 3 bytes shorter!

Rebuild your app, and… viola upload to AppStore succeeded!

***NOTE: Sure, you MUST check your app functionality not broken.
I did for mine app and it works like a charm.***

Comment: I've performed additional search across PhoneGap sources (link in question comments). UIDevice.uniqueIdentifier is only used to "pack" deviceProperties variable as dictionary, which is than passed to page as JSON calling [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:deviceProperties]. Here is what we see in logs: Device initialization: DeviceInfo = {"name":"Simulator","uuid":"XXX","platform":"Simulator","gap":"1.0.0","version":"5.0","connection":{"type":"wifi"}}; With the above solution we'll have "uuid":"5.0" for example. So, if you don't use DeviceInfo.uuid in your JS, my solution is safe.

Comment: Your hack saved me hours of wasted time, I'm using PhoneGap 1.3.0 and don't want to upgrade. Got iHex from the Mac store, it allows entry in text or hex and changed 'uniqueIdentifier' to 'systemVersion   ' add three spaces at the end which translated to hex 00 00 00 and all worked fine. I don't use the uuid field so don't care about its value.

Answer (score 0):

Nope.  Apple is your issue here.  You have to update your PhoneGap to at least 2.5, see posting here: 
https://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2013/05/01/cordovaphonegap-and-the-new-apple-app-store-requirements/

And you have to update any plugin or native you wrote to not use uuid.

Comment: Thanks. As I say, there are no time/resources to perform an upgrade. The project is very complex, custom plugins have 20+ functions, a lot of "magic" performed additionally with managed WebView, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using phonegap 1.2.0 but the above "hack" didnt work for me - it gave me an error

```
ld: file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7 slice:
```

So instead I found a much easier solution - locate the PhoneGapLib.xcodeproj that gets installed when you install phonegap and open it, then search for the "uniqueIdentifier" call.

Then I used the below code taken from here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/9458313/1851746) in order to substitute the UUID value -

```
- (NSString *)getUUID
{
    NSString *UUID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"uniqueID"];
    if (!UUID)
    {
        CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
        CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
        CFRelease(theUUID);
        UUID = [(__bridge NSString*)string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-"withString:@""];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:UUID forKey:@"uniqueID"];
    }
    return UUID;
}
```

Calling this method with [self getUUID] instead of uniqueIdentifier works though for some reason it led to an error with a subsequent value added to the dictionary for the phonegap version. So I just hard coded this instead in the same block as the above.

Then change target to "PhoneGap", build, then go to the Products folder and open location in finder, copy the framework folder, and replace the one found in Users/Shared/PhoneGap/Frameworks.

Project should compile and be accepted to the App Store